# A static character prefix in UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uitextfield

Is there a built-in way to add a character prefix to a `UITextField` like the screenshot below?

[image]

If no, what is the best, most straight-forward way to accomplish this? I am thinking the `background` property might be able to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply adding a gray `UILabel` on top of the `UITextField` does the trick:

[image: 001]  [image: 002]

Note that the `UILabel` behaves like a background image, the entered text stays on top:

[image: 003]

**UPDATE**

Additionally you can add some padding to the `UITextField` using the following code:

```
UIView *thePadding = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
theTextField.leftView = thePadding;
theTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

This way the text cannot cover the prefix character.
Adjust the rect to make it working properly in your situation.

Comment: with this (as you point out) there is a risk of text running on top of the UILabel. thats not desirable

Comment: I assumed the questioner did not care about the input covering the character prefix since a background property was suggested in the question. Anyway, added simple solution to prevent the input from covering the prefix character.

Comment: So why not use the UILabel as thePadding UIView?

Answer (score 9):

Following on from [Anne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388037/anne) code you can also do this directly in code without the UILabel in IB and UIView in code:

```
UILabel *poundLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
poundLabel.text = @"£";
[self.paymentAmount setLeftView:poundLabel];
[self.paymentAmount setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Ditiet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12932971/242933) (on retina using size 15 system font), the text field positioned its text 0.5 points too close to the dollar sign. Using `-sizeWithAttributes:`, I fit the `width` of the dollar sign label to about 8.5 but the text field positioned its text at an `x` of 8 (the floor of the left view's width).

I found two solutions to perfect the relative positioning between the dollar sign (left view) & text.

### Solution 1: Right Align the Dollar Sign

Set the dollar sign label's width to the ceiling of the width of the dollar sign (or hard code it). Then, right align the dollar sign label's text.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 120, 44)];
textField.font = font;
NSString *dollarSignText = @"$";
CGSize size = [dollarSignText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
UILabel *dollarSignLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ceilf(size.width), 44)];
dollarSignLabel.font = font;
dollarSignLabel.text = dollarSignText;
dollarSignLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
textField.leftView = dollarSignLabel;
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Although this solution perfects the relative positioning between the dollar sign label (left view) & text, it will likely increase the width of the dollar sign label a bit (not more than 1 pt), causing the same increase to the text field's width and shifting all the text to the right by the same amount.

I don't recommend this solution if the text field's height will change, e.g., due to Auto Layout (or autoresizing).

### Solution 2: Subclass UITextField & Override Its Positioning

This solution supports you're using Auto Layout (or autoresizing) to adjust the text field's height.

```
// VVMAmountTextField.h

@import UIKit;

@interface VVMAmountTextField : UITextField

@end


// VVMAmountTextField.m

#import "VVMAmountTextField.h"

@implementation VVMAmountTextField

#pragma mark - UIView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        self.font = font;
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
        self.placeholder = @"0.00";

        // Set leftView to dollarSignLabel ($).
        UILabel *dollarSignLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        dollarSignLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        dollarSignLabel.font = font;
        dollarSignLabel.text = @"$";
        self.leftView = dollarSignLabel;
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UITextField

// Override positioning to make things pixel perfect.

#define DOLLAR_SIGN_WIDTH() [((UILabel *)self.leftView).text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.font}].width

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    bounds = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    bounds.origin.x = DOLLAR_SIGN_WIDTH();
    return bounds;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    bounds = [super editingRectForBounds:bounds];
    bounds.origin.x = DOLLAR_SIGN_WIDTH();
    return bounds;
}

- (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    bounds.size.width = DOLLAR_SIGN_WIDTH();
    return bounds;
}

@end
```

## Conclusion

Either solution seems to work well. Solution 1 will likely cause a shift but has less code and still looks pixel-perfect. I only thought of it after Solution 2. Solution 2 is elegant and supports you're using Auto Layout (or autoresizing) to adjust the text field's height.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think you can do this as part of `UITextField` alone.

One way I can thing of is to make your `UITextField` borderless and keep a `UILabel` on the left (but adjacent) of the `UITextField`. And finally if you want border than put these 2 elements (UITextField and UILabel) inside a UIView and give border to this view. This setup should look exactly same as the image you have put up.

Let me know if this works out.

**UPDATE**: you could do as @Anne points but there is a risk of text running on top of the UILabel. I feel what I suggested is better.

Comment: This way the `UITextField` will not become first responder in case the user clicks on the prefix character.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Anne's answer. You could also make it a UIImageView and use any image you want there. With a UIImageView you can set the background to be white so text will tuck underneath it.